# Confused about the use of variables w/ logical quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Sorry if this is a really dumb question, but...

After reading How to Prove it, I've become a little confused. On page 70, an example stating something similar to this is provided:

$[\exists x P(x) \land \exists x Q(x)]$ and  $\exists x [P(x) \land Q(x)]$ are two different things,

and says that for the first statement, there could be a person that makes p(x) true, and there could be a *different* person that makes q(x) true.

I thought that if we picked an x value, it would apply across the whole statement? What is the purpose of using different variable names if not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read back about bounded variables. The formula on the left can be rewritten as $\exists x P(x) \land \exists y Q(y)$. The $x$ in each of the components in $\exists x P(x) \land \exists x Q(x)$ is bounded. They are possibly different $x$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is that the two formulae are **not** equivalent.

Let $P(x)$ interpreted as "x is Even" and $Q(x)$ interpreted as "x is Odd".

Clearly, in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* :

> [∃xP(x)∧∃xQ(x)] is *true* : $2$ is an *even* number and $1$ is an *odd* number,

while :

> ∃x[P(x)∧Q(x)] is *false* : there is **no** number which is both even and odd.

In this formula the *scope* of the quantifier $\exists x$ is the whole formula $[P(x)∧Q(x)]$; thus, when you "pick" an $x$, in order to satisfy the formula it is necessary that for **that** $x$ both $P$ and $Q$ holds.

In the previous formula, the two quantifiers $\exists x$ have different *scope* : the first one "acts on" $P(x)$ only and the second one on $Q(x)$. Thus, in order to satisfy the formula, we have the "freedom" to "pick" an $x$ for which $P$ holds and a *different* one for which $Q$ holds.

Answer (score 4):

The formula $\exists x P(x)$ is a single quantified statement, and the value of $x$ is the same value throughout that statement.

The formula $\exists x Q(x)$ also is a single quantified statement, and the value of $x$ is the same value throughout that statement.

The formula $[\exists x P(x) \land \exists x Q(x)]$ is not a single quantified statement. It is the conjunction of two separate quantified statements. *Within* each of those statements, whatever value of $x$ is used is the same value for the whole statement.

There is actually no reason to use different variable names in the two parts of the conjunction. On the other hand, we *can* use different variable names if we like, since the variable in each quantified statement is independent of the other.

In other cases, where one quantifier appears *inside* another quantified statement, for example, $\exists x [\exists y R(x,y)]$, then it actually *does* matter that the two variable names are different. But in that case, the $\exists y$ is showing up before the "end" of the statement that started with $\exists x$, so the variable $x$ is still "in use" at that point.